# Retrieving user information with access token - Facebook developer

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, access-token

I'm developing a Facebook application, and I want to retrieve some of the user's information on a side server while they are using the application.

In order to make that possible, I store the users access token in my database and pass it to the other server.

However, I am not sure how to use the access token to retrieve the user information. I am using the PHP SDK, and here is the usual code:

```
require '../src/facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '',
  'secret' => '',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

Where can I declare the access token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very simple. If you enter a url like `https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=theuseraccesstoken` (in your browser) you will receive a json file with the user information.

I'm pretty sure the facebook php sdk have a built in mechanism to do that (I'm a c# coder), but you are looking in the wrong place, because no api key or secret is necessary to access user information using a access token.

**UPDATE1:**

I think it works like this in the sdk

```
$facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

**UPDATE2:**

Or like this

```
$user = $facebook->api('me?access_token='.$access_token);
```

Comment: then it should be something like $user = $facebook->api('/me?'.$access_token);

Comment: but it doesnt work, it says i must use an acces token, that means its not being declared in the correct place

Comment: there's another alternative. take a look and choose one. glad to help. best.

Answer (score 1):

If the user is logged in, make:

```
$facebook->api('/me');
```

I will give you an array with information about the user.

Comment: he is getting the information from the database in another server, so the user is not logged.